Docker Debug from Visual Studio 2022 works and opens the Web API, but trying to run image from Powershell does not work, port not being listened
Code is present in https://github.com/Coop202406/CountryAPI
Trying to run the same image from Visual Studio and from Powershell. The image is run in a container in both cases, the container created by Visual Studio Docker Debug works but the container run from the Powersehll does not work when the localhost 8080 is searched.
Below is the command used to run image from Powershell
$ docker run --rm -it -p 8080 -p 8081 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http//+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=8081 -e ASPNETCORE_KestrelCertificatesDefaultPassword="webapp" -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -e ASPNETCORE_KestrelCertificatesDefaultPath=c:\https\aspnetapp.pfx -v $env:USERPROFILE.aspnet\https:C:\https\ countryapi:dev

The images show the difference in containers running from docker debug
and image run from powershell
Tried tracing the VS output console, difference in the build mount.
Tried docker.exe run -p :8080 <image id>, opens listening to port but says localhost:port not found
UPDATE:
Got port listening for 8080 when running from the terminal but not for port 8081, already tried trusting the dotnet dev-certs https --trust
docker run -p :8080 -p :8081 <image ID>

What shows from container log now after running image from powershell

By default the :dev image produced by Visual Studio for debugging in the Debug configuration is not a full runnable image (see docs). That image relies on VS supplying volume mounts to use your locally built version to speed up incremental runs. You can right-click on the Dockerfile and select "Build Docker Image" to get a fully built image.

